# Need help connecting 10 LED USB powered lights to one power source

Tags: led, low-voltage, usb-pd

I need help to connect 10 LED string lights into single plug. I wanted to make sure I have enough power, but not burn out the lights.

[image: this is what i'm planning to do]

Comment: You needn't add "need help" in your question title. Simply by posting a question we can infer that you require assistance.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this site.

Comment: Nick, you just need a Buck converter in between the 12V out and the 5V-in. So, instead of "can i", ask "how can i", and you will get better success. Specifically, you can ask, "I want to do this:" and change the above picture to include a rectangle with "Buck Converter" between the 12V-out and the 5V-in, and say, "Please help me either pick a buck converter or make a buck converter that will do this." Then provide a "power budget" saying, "each widget draws a max of 0.25 Watt, so I have to provide a max of 10*0.25W=2.5W." And....  Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange!

Comment: So ask a "New and improved" question, please!

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Presumably, by educating new users.

Comment: @Nick You'll need more than a buck converter if those LED strings use 5W each, 12V * 3A = 36W, with ten 5W LED strings you'd need 50W plus some extra for the losses in the converter and a safety factor. In that case you'd need a higher wattage supply and if you're going to replace the supply you may as well just go with a 5V one that will handle the current of ten LED strings. If they are actually 5W you'd want at least a 60W supply for a 20% safety margin.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and understanding. I will try using the 36V buck converter and see if the LED's work and if needed change to a 50V power adapter to make sure each LED gets the required 5V.

Comment: @Nick I think you are confusing volts and watts. I would recommend looking at some basic electronics tutorials online before proceeding further.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't connect a 12V supply into devices that are rated for only 5V.